# How can I obtain reliable variance estimates for an exposure with low frequency?

Tags: logistic, bootstrap, rare-events

I have a sample of 3000 observations. I wish to model the effect of a rare binary exposure (frequency of less than 50) on a binary outcome (frequency of 300). I also wish to adjust for approximately five other confounding variables. I intend to use a logistic regression model.

I understand that sparse data cells will become an issue here, as the 50 observations with the binary exposure will be split amongst the covariates and the outcome. The sparse data will lead to inflated standard errors and unreliable estimates of variance.

**What approaches can I use to obtain reliable estimates of variance in this case?**

Comment: Consider Firth logistic regression as implemented in the `brglm2` R package.

Comment: All discussion of Firth logistic regression I can find on the web focuses on applying it to situations with rare outcomes. Do you know of a reference that suggests that Firth logistic regression can also be used for rare exposures?